# How to change the class of the parent element with different forms with angular2+ or css?

Tags: css, angular, user-interface

I have a list of elements with a header, body and a checkbox to display the body, Like accordion:

```
        <form class="search-box" [ngClass]="{'classname' : condition}">
            <input
                (click)="addClasstoBody"
                type="checkbox"
                name="showBody"
            />
            <header>
                <span class="body">
                    Body
                </span>
            </header> </div>
           <div class="search-box" [ngClass]="{'classname' : condition}">
            <input
                (click)="addClasstoBody"
                type="checkbox"
                name="showBody"
            />
            <header>
                <span class="body">
                    Body
                </span>
            </header></form>
```

With the easy way of setting on true by add the class to all the components.

Can I use something like `form.checkbox.checked`?

Comment: should be `input[type="checkbox"]:checked`, see e.g. [developer.mozilla.org/css/:checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)

Answer (score 0):

i edited the answer

create elementRef and bind to your HTML element
then pass the elementRef onClick for further manipulate

edit your component.ts

```
...
  @ViewChild('container1') container1: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('container2') container2: ElementRef;
....

    addClasstoBody(containerModel: HTMLElement, event){
    var targetContainer = event.target;
    var isChecked = targetContainer.checked;
    console.dir(isChecked)
    console.dir(containerModel)
    console.dir(event)

    if(isChecked){
      containerModel.classList.add("show");
    }else{
      containerModel.classList.remove("show");
    }
  }
```

edit your component.html

```
<form class="search-box">
    <div [ngClass]="{'classname' : true}" #container1>
        <input
            (click)="addClasstoBody(container1, $event)"
            type="checkbox"
            name="showBody"
            [(ngModel)]="container1.isCheck"
        >
        <header>
            <span class="body">
                Body1
            </span>
        </header>
    </div>
   <div class="search-box" [ngClass]="{'classname' : true}" #container2>
        <input
            (click)="addClasstoBody(container2, $event)"
            type="checkbox"
            name="showBody"
            [(ngModel)]="container2.isCheck"
        >
        <header>
            <span class="body">
                Body2
            </span>
        </header>
    </div>
</form>
```

you may also did all in the html, remove the addClasstoBody function but edit your container as below

```
<div [ngClass]="{'classname' : container1.isCheck}" #container1>
```

Comment: Yes but how a change the class of only the first parent? condtion = true will change all the parent classes